# intermittent 401s from static resources

Tags: http, iis, iis-6

I am seeing something really strange here on one of the sites I am working on. A number of static files (images, css or js) intermittently return 401 (unauthorized). This only occurs in UAT environment, but not dev nor live.

If I clear browser cache and load the site, everything works fine - 200s returned across the board. If I hit F5 right after *some* of the files will return 401. Observed this both in Firebug console and Fiddler.
The set of files that return 401 is semi-consistent. I can refresh page ~5 times before it changes.

Strangely enough Firebug NET panel shows very same requests as returning 304 (not modified). Site appearance is unaffected by these errors, so I assume this is just Firebug issue where it fails to properly show 401s when it can read them from cache.

If I purge browser cache and try again - everything will load fine (200 returned).

Headers from the failed requests

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Content-Length: 1656
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Microsoft-IIS/6.0
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="xxxxxx.tld"
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Thu, 27 Oct 2011 16:12:45 GMT
Proxy-Support: Session-Based-Authentication
```

You may notice auth challenge headers in the response, which is not surprising - the site is protected. The surprising part is that they appear after user was already authenticated and loaded main page just fine. More so, they only appear only on cached files that loaded fine a second ago.

Comment: You should also be able to check the IIS logs on the server to see if you get a more detailed error message, if in fact one exists.